# Determine moving direction based on touch location

Tags: c++, ios

I am trying to figure out the best way to determine which direction to move based on the users touch on the screen. So say i get a 2d position 23x and 320y i need to then return one of the following LEFT,RIGHT,UP,DOWN.

Currently the code i am using isn't very reliable and i am wondering if someone can advise me on a better way of doing it.

Thanks

```
if (at_position.x <= width*2/3 && at_position.x >= width*1/3 && at_position.y <= this->screenHeight*2/3)
{
    return UP;

}
else if (at_position.x <= width*2/3 && at_position.x >= width*1/3 && at_position.y >= this->screenHeight*1/3)
{
    return DOWN;      
}
else if (at_position.x <= this->screenWidth*2/3 && at_position.y >= this->screenHeight*1/3 && at_position.y <= this->screenHeight*2/3)
{
   return LEFT;         
}
else if (at_position.x <= this->screenWidth*1/3 && at_position.y >= this->screenHeight*1/3 && at_position.y <= this->screenHeight*2/3)
{
   return RIGHT;        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with complex solutions like other people suggest (like calculating a vector to the point where the user tapped). You're not solving a difficult math problem, you just need to ckeck if the point is within some area. So don't over-complicate things.

```
//lets you check if point a is between the boundaies, which in your case are either 
//X or Y coordinates. 
bool isBetween( int a, int firstBoundary, int secondBoundary)
{
   return (a >= firstBoundary && a <= secondBoundary);
}

if (isBetween(at_position.x, width*1/3, width*2/3))
{
    if(at_position.y <= this->screenHeight*2/3)
        return UP;
    else if(at_position.y >= this->screenHeight*1/3)
        return DOWN;      
}
else if (isBetween(at_position.y, this->screenHeight*1/3, this->screenHeight*2/3))
{
    if(at_position.x <= this->screenWidth*2/3)
       return LEFT;         
    else if(at_position.y <= this->screenHeight*2/3)
       return RIGHT;
}
```

This is, of course, still not the best-looking code, but given what it needs to do, it's not the worst, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

you can calculate a vector based on the old and new position: newX - oldX, newY - oldY, and this can be used as an angle, for determining the direction just convert the range 0-360 (angle) to 0-3 (enum values). for a more precise method make a short delay (0.1s) before determining the direction based on the new position

for converting the vector to an angle in range [0 to 2*PI] use

```
C#:
float angle = Math.Atan2(newY - oldY, newX - oldX) + Math.PI;
```

convert this to degrees with

```
C#:
angle = angle * (180 / Math.PI);
```

convert this to enum value

```
C#:
int e = (int)angle / 90; //will give 0 for 0-90, 1 for 90-180, 2 for 180-270...
```

then your enum could look like this

```
C#:
enum dir {
    R = 0, D = 1, L = 2, U = 3 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to calculate the angle of direction vector and make suggestion based on it

```
vec2 dir = ...
float angle = atan2f(dir.y, dir.x) + M_PI; //angle is in range [0, 2*PI] now
if (angle > 7 * M_PI / 4 && angle <= M_PI / 4) {//right}
else if (angle > M_PI / 4 && angle <= 3 * M_PI / 4) {//top}
//and so on
```

To calculate `dir` you need to point. One is - your current touch location. The second one can be `prev touch position` position or some fixed point (the center of the screen for example)

In case you have this points:

```
vec2 dir = currentTouchPoint - prevPoint; //or origin
```

Comment: given the original question, how to calculate `dir` is not trivial (there is only one sample, not two).

Comment: @KillianDS: you can't determine the direction if you have just one touch. The second point should be selected in any way

Comment: Sorry i probably didnt make myself clear enough. Based on the area of the screen they touch i want to determine whether to move the character left,right,up or down so if they click mostly towards the left of the screen and neither significantly up or down i would return left, does that make sense?

Comment: @JonathanDixon: If you have a character then you should calculate `dir` as `dir = touchLocation - characterPosition`

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way:

Declare this struc.

```
typedef enum {
    kDirecLeft = 1,
    kDirecRight,
    kDirecUp,
    kDirecDown,
}SwipDirection;
```

Use these two member variable:

```
CGPoint             mSwipTouch1;
CGPoint             mSwipTouch2;
```

Initialize mSwipTouch1 in TouchesBegan and mSwipTouch2 in TouchesEnded
.

```
-(void)checkForDirection
{
    SwipDirection direction;

    bool isValidSwip = false;

    float swipXLength = ABS(mSwipTouch1.x-mSwipTouch2.x) ;
    float swipYLength = ABS(mSwipTouch1.y-mSwipTouch2.y) ;

    float swipDistance ; 

    if(swipXLength > swipYLength)  // Left/Right swip
    {
        swipDistance = swipXLength;

        if(swipXLength > MIN_SWIP_LENGHT)
        {
            if(mSwipTouch1.x > mSwipTouch2.x) //Left swip
            {
                DEBUG_LOG("Left swip\n") ;
                direction = kDirecLeft ; 
                isValidSwip = true;
            }
            else
            {
                DEBUG_LOG("Right swip\n") ;
                direction = kDirecRight ;
                isValidSwip = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else  // Up/Down Swip
    {
        swipDistance = swipYLength;

        if(swipYLength > MIN_SWIP_LENGHT)
        {
            if(mSwipTouch1.y > mSwipTouch2.y) //Left swip
            {
                DEBUG_LOG("Down swip\n") ;
                direction = kDirecDown ;
                isValidSwip = true;
            }
            else
            {
                DEBUG_LOG("Up swip\n") ;
                direction = kDirecUp ;
                isValidSwip = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if(isValidSwip)
        [self process:direction];
}

-(void)process:(SwipDirection)direc
{
    switch(direc)
    {
      case kDirecLeft:
           [self moveLeft];
            break;
        case kDirecRight:
            [self moveRight];
            break;

        case kDirecDown:
            [self moveDown];
            break;

        case kDirecUp:
            [self moveUp];
            break;
        default:
            break;    
    }
}
```